# href tag breaks vue template component

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to add a href link with a variable in my vue template, for some reason it keeps breaking and I have no clue why, it's trying to reference it as a variable rather than a link. the issue is with the "/post/update" href. the "/view-user/ + post.user.id" works fine

```
<template>
<div id="content">
    <div class="post">
        <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
        <p>{{post.content}}</p>
        <a :href="/view-user/ + post.user.id">
            {{post.user.username}}
        </a>
        <p>{{ post.created_at.split(".")[0] }}</p>
        <a :href="/post/update/ + post.id">Edit</a>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <comment :id="id"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static part of the href value should be wrapped by `''` as string :

```
 <a :href="'/view-user/' + post.user.id">
```

or string template :

```
 <a :href="`/view-user/${post.user.id}`">
```

in your case it's evaluated as expression.